# How do I convert a string into bytes in python?

Tags: python, json, string, unicode, type-conversion

In my code, I encode a string with utf-8. I get the output, convert it to a string, and send it to my other program. The other program gets this string, but, when I try to decode the string, it gives me an error, AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'. I need to send the encoded data as a string because my other program receives it in a json. My first program is in python 3, and the other program is in python 2.

```
# my first program
x = u"宇宙"
x = str(x.encode('utf-8'))


# my other program
text = x.decode('utf-8')
print(text)
```

What should I do to convert the string received by the second program to bytes so the decode works?

Comment: if you have a string decode has already toke place. Usually this is done by web frameworks transparently, if you need bytes, you should encode it again

Comment: Python3 here: a string is already decoded (it is Unicode, do not care about the internal encoding). You encode a string. The encoding will transform a letter (e.g. A) into a byte sequence.  Note: `print` could also give unexpected results, because of operating system (and locale) expected encoding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most important part to properly answer this is the information on *how* you pass these objetcts to the Python2 program: you are using JSON.

So, stay with me:

After you do the `.encode` step in program 1, you have a bytes object. By calling `str(...)` on it, you are just putting a escaping layer on this bytes object, and turning it back to a string - but when this string is written as is to a file, or transmited over the network, it will be encoded again - any non-ASCII tokens are usually escaped with the `\u` prefix and the codepoint for each character - but the original Chinese chracters themselves are now encoded in utf-8 and doubly-escaped.

Python's JSON load methods already decode the contents of json data into text-strings: so a decode method is not to be expected at all.

**In short**: to pass data around, simply encode your original text as JSON in the first program, and do not botter with any decoding after `json.load` on the target Python 2 program:

```
# my first program
x = "宇宙"
# No str-encode-decode dance needed here.
...
data =  json.dumps({"example_key": x, ...})
# code to transmit json string by network or file as it is...


# my other program
text = json.loads(data)["example_key"]
# text is a Unicode text string ready to be used!
```

As you are doing, you are probably gettint the text doubly-encoded - I will mimick it on the Python 3 console. I will print the result from each step so you can undestand the transforms that are taking place.

```
In [1]: import json

In [2]: x = "宇宙"

In [3]: print(x.encode("utf-8"))
b'\xe5\xae\x87\xe5\xae\x99'

In [4]: text = str(x.encode("utf-8"))

In [5]: print(text)
b'\xe5\xae\x87\xe5\xae\x99'

In [6]: json_data = json.dumps(text)

In [7]: print(json_data)
"b'\\xe5\\xae\\x87\\xe5\\xae\\x99'"
# as you can see, it is doubly escaped, and it is mostly useless in this form

In [8]: recovered_from_json = json.loads(json_data)

In [9]: print(recovered_from_json)
b'\xe5\xae\x87\xe5\xae\x99'

In [10]: print(repr(recovered_from_json))
"b'\\xe5\\xae\\x87\\xe5\\xae\\x99'"

In [11]: # and if you have data like this in files/databases you need to recover:

In [12]: import ast

In [13]: recovered_text = ast.literal_eval(recovered_from_json).decode("utf-8")

In [14]: print(recovered_text)
宇宙
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue when decoding stringified bytes received in a JSON payload:

```py
print(value)
>>> "b'text-here'"
```

Encoding the string only compounded the problem by adding another layer of wrapping:

```py
encoded = value.encode("utf-8")
print(encoded)
>>> b"b'text-here'"
```

And this solution from @jsbueno didn't work for me - I got a `json.decoder.JSONDecodeError`:

```
recovered_from_json = json.loads(json_data)
```

---

**SOLUTION**

You need to evaluate the string to expose the wrapped bytes object:

```py
import ast

as_bytes = ast.literal_eval(value)
print(as_bytes)
>>> b'text-here'
```

Then you can decode to string:

```
decoded = value.decode()
print(decoded)
>>> 'text-here'
```

As noted by @snakecharmerb, you shouldn't use `eval()` as it opens you up to running potentially dangerous commands if input is not checked or sanitized (see this old but illustrative [blog post](https://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201206/eval_really_is_dangerous.html))

Comment: Using `eval` like this is most unwise - `ast.literal_eval` is better and safer for this particular case.

Answer (score -1):

Mainly you are dealing with two different python version and it has the library issue.

[six](https://six.readthedocs.io/) library solve this issue.

> Six provides simple utilities for wrapping over differences between Python 2 and Python 3. It is intended to support codebases that work on both Python 2 and 3 without modification.

use this library and decode in this way.

```
import six

def bytes_to_str(s, encoding='utf-8'):
    """Returns a str if a bytes object is given."""
    if six.PY2 and isinstance(s, bytes):
        return s.decode(encoding)
    return s

text = bytes_to_str(x)
print(text)
```

Comment: This particular issue has not to do with the difference between Python 2 and 3, and rather, with double-encoding. Check my answer for details.